# My admin not working during install payment charge extension installation process

Tags: import, magento-1.9, magmi

I need to import `Bulk description of products`, in my csv 1200 records are there, 800 records import successfully remaining not import, i get error like :

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value:
>   '\xA0Ideal...' for column 'value' at row 1

Answer (score 0):

save your file using notepad++  or the one that you like and select UTF-8
you are surely using some other format that it is NOT utf-8

Comment: How can i save my EXCEL sheet using notepad ++, just past content check whether its UTF-* or not